# best way to edit go template (helm template) file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I want to add preStop hook in public helm chart and then distribute that chart to different teams, whats the best way to achieve this programmatically?

source template example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "test.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "test.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "test.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "test.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: some-static-name
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
    {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

i want to add `lifecycle.preStop` block after `- name: some-static-name`, eg.

```
...
...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: some-static-name
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: [
                  "sh", "-c",
                  "sleep 5",
                ]
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
...
...
```

what would be the best way to achieve this instead of using `sed` or similar programs?

Comment: Did you come up with something?
I'm after doing almost the same thing, except for container resource requests.

I'm currently looking at the go lib https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3#readme-docs

Comment: this was for istio helm chart, I changed my helm chart approach to different one, i.e. use istioctl command with "overlays" option to override generated manifest

I dont think my solution will help you as it was istio specific